# Is there any downsides to have BaseFragment with an argument?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I use Jatpack navigation, this is my declaration of BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<BINDING : ViewDataBinding, VIEW_MODEL : BaseViewModel>(private val layoutId: Int) : Fragment() {...}
```

so I can have fragments like this:

```
class DocumentsFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentDocumentsBinding, DocumentsViewModel>(R.layout.fragment_documents) {
```

My question is, we know we should never have parameters in Fragments to restore states and all, but could Base fragments have them?

Answer (score 1):

Not in this case because there is now a constructor for doing exactly that

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#Fragment(int)

I would recommend you to analyze it and try to adapt to it, you dont need it in the base fragment.

The parametyzed types thougth seem bad because if you wish to use other type of viewmodel you shoot your self in the foot. By example, does you base view model is a `AndroidViewModel`? You might need that but cant because you lock your self out. There are other view model types.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay `FragmentManager` only needs Fragment classes that are added to it to have zero-argument constructor since they're the one that will be reflected.

It's irrelevant if that constructor proceeds to invoke super constructor with arguments.

Even [androidx.Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#Fragment(int)) has an overload that takes `layoutId` to inflate instead of overriding `onCreateView`:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.my_fragment)
```